# Laravel 5 oauth with both social and local accounts

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, oauth

everyone!

In my app I want to have an abily to login from account in social networks as well as from accounts registered localy and have access to the same database on my server.

What I mean:

> Scenario 1:
> User pressed "login with facebook"
> -> Get access to application features
>
> Scenario 2:
> User pressed "login with account registred localy on my server"
> -> Get access to application features

If I login from local account then it's easy to check auth data and grant access.
If I login in my app from twitter for example and got their tokens, how could I use them to access data on my server?

I found information only about how to make local login using Passport or using social services using Socialite but not both at the same time.

Comment: social login and native login are completely doable separately you can integrate passport and socialite they are for different purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out, it's actually easy to implement using only Socialite with standart auth. I misunderstood the concept of oauth so there is no need for passport at all.